# Hardware optimizations using Qualcomm Snapdragon 800 and Adreno 330

Tags: opencv, opencl, neon, flann, linaro

I am developing a real-time computer vision project that runs on an Ubuntu (Linaro) board with an ARM CPU (Snapdragon 800).

Some parts of the software operate on HD images, huge amount of data. This slows the execution and acts as a bottleneck.

These operations include:

- Finding **all** local minimum and maximum values in a 2D array (image). Currenly, it is implemented using the naive, trivial way.
- Building a KD-Tree and performing a K-Nearest-Neighbors search. This is currently done using the FLANN library included in OpenCV.

I am looking for ways to utilize the available Adreno 330 GPU, and accelerate these computations.

I was looking at OpenCL, but I found out that it is supported on Adreno 330 only as an "embedded profile", something that I do not what it is, and how it affects things.

I also heard about NEON in ARM processors, but I do not know how will it be any use for me.

Any help, tips and links will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Avi